# How to see full data in trace

Tags: php, debugging, stack-trace, php-5.5

I am using php 5.5.
When I throw exception I get (Notice the line marked #1)
Trace

```
#0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(289): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(Array, 300)
#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(211): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->rcpt('yabamartin@s...')
#2 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(SiTEL_Communication_Mail))
#4 /lms2/production/PROD010D/application/lib/SiTEL/eMail.php(259): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
```

As you can see, the input to the function is truncated, so it is hard for me to debug the issue without seeing the full data that was passed

I assume it is something in php.ini? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to see the value being passed to that function, you could simply go to that file and that line "Smtp.php(211)", and use var_dump($the_var) to see the full value of that variable being passed as an argument.

Comment: I am doing exactly that when I debug the problem. but if I see it in the logs, which are generated when I get an Exception thrown, will save me much time (and I won't need to potentialy debug on production)